# How to add files to android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using the cordova filePicker plugin (MFilechooser), I see the  filechooser from emulator (cordova emulate android). However, I don't know how to transfer a file from my PC to the emulator directory so I can select it.

Can you please give me some suggestion on how to this action.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use **adb** comand line utility from Android SDK.
Example of command:
     adb push /local/path/to/file/on/pc /path/to/file/in/emulator

Substitute appropriate paths in example above.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the "USB debugging" option in the emulator first and then open the Android Device Monitor --> DDMS perspective --> Select the emulator. You should be able to see the options enabled when you select a file or folder from file explorer.

Select "Push a file onto the device" option to add files to sd card of your emulator or device.

[View image showing the explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALQgB.png)